# progressbar (cyclic) show while show activity

Tags: android, android-activity, progress-bar

i want to put progressbar while the oncreat finish...it's take about 10 second to strat activty and show View and prepare mediaplayer...
what i can use to show progressbar until It show the views and prepare media player..
If there any tutorial videos please could you send it in comment

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

         final  String   url = "url";

play = (Button)findViewById(R.id.play);
pause = (Button)findViewById(R.id.pause);
seekbar = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seekBar1);
am=(AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
int max = am.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
int min = am.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

seekbar.setMax(max);
seekbar.setProgress(min);
seekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener( this);

mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();


try {
    mediaPlayer.setDataSource(url);
} catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (SecurityException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IllegalStateException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
try {

    mediaPlayer.prepare();
} catch (IllegalStateException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} // might take long! (for buffering, etc)



 play.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

             Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "text", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    mediaPlayer.start();
                }});


 pause.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

             mediaPlayer.pause();


    }} );



    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after

`mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();`

add this code

```
ProgressDialog  pd = new ProgressDialog(this);
        pd.setMessage("your message");
            pd.setCancelable(false);
        pd.setIndeterminate(true);

            //Show Dialog
            pd.show();
```

and if you want to cancel or remove Dialog simply call `pd.dismiss();`